# TensorFlow: how find out that tensor already created

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to create big tensor with shape 42000x28x28, data comes as a ArrayBuffer, let's assume that I create tensor something like that:

```
tf.tensor4d(new Uint8Array(xsTrainBuffer), [42000 * 0.9, 28, 28, 1]).div<Tensor<Rank.R4>>(255);
```

The question is - how find out that tensor is already prepared and I may use it in model training, since this function doesn't return any promise, but as for me it looks a little bit weird consider this operation as synchronous one.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a better approach would be the [tf.data.array()](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#data.array) function. This will create a [DataSet](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#class:data.Dataset) for you that is ideal for working with large amounts of data.

While the function itself is synchronous, it does a lazy loading of the data - so immediately after you call the function, if you try to log the data, it will show empty. However, use the [forEachAsync()](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#tf.data.Dataset.forEachAsync) function to log the data and you will see that it reads it correctly.

Check out this [iris-fitDataset](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/blob/aad9b8151458ef6a8d00bcbaa6f6cb12584401af/iris-fitDataset/data.js) example where they use the `tf.data.array()` function.

Note that Dataset's have their own model functions such as `fitDataset()` instead of `fit()` so you don't have to convert the Dataset into anything else.